# Reloading DataTable.js fnServer fnDraw

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, datatables, refresh

First I initiate all datatables by the following code (there are more options, but I'm adding a minimum for this example). The code bellow is working and start all datatables, if the datatable has a search, it'll initialise the `fnServerParams` with the parameters. (the parameters are going to the function on the codebehind and working).

```
var dt = jQuery(".dataTable");
if(jQuery().dataTable && dt.length > 0) {
    dt.each(function () {
        var e = {
            sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        };
        // If has external filters
        if(!!jQuery(this).data("searchbox")) {
            var search_box = jQuery(jQuery(this).data("searchbox"));

            var additional_filters = [];
            jQuery.each(search_box.find('input,select'), function(i, v){
                additional_filters.push({
                    name: jQuery(v).attr('name'),
                    value: jQuery(v).val()
                });
            });

            if (additional_filters.length > 0) {
                e.fnServerParams = function (aoData) {
                    for (var i=0; i < additional_filters.length; i++) {
                        var filter = additional_filters[i];
                        aoData.push( { "name": filter.name, "value": filter.value } );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        jQuery(this).dataTable(e);
    });
}
```

The problem is when I call my function `RefreshDataTables()` by a click/change event. In the function I used this simplified version to refresh:

*PS: All code below is to be interpreted that is **inside** `RefreshDataTables()`*

```
var dt = jQuery(".dataTable");
if(jQuery().dataTable && dt.length > 0) {
    dt.each(function () {
        var $oTable = jQuery(this).dataTable();
        $oTable.fnDraw();
    });
}
```

But it doesn't update the changes on the inputs/selects of the search. it keep the same from the before. So I tried this code base on [this answer](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/35130/#Comment_35130):

```
var dt = jQuery(".dataTable");
if(jQuery().dataTable && dt.length > 0) {
    dt.each(function () {
        var $oTable = jQuery(this).dataTable();
        var search_box = jQuery(jQuery(this).data("searchbox"));

        var additional_filters = [];

        jQuery.each(search_box.find('input,select'), function(i, v){
            additional_filters.push({
                name: jQuery(v).attr('name'),
                value: jQuery(v).val()
            });
        });

        if (additional_filters.length > 0) {
            $oTable._fnServerParams = function (aoData) {
                for (var i=0; i < additional_filters.length; i++) {
                    var filter = additional_filters[i];
                    aoData.push( { "name": filter.name, "value": filter.value } );
                }
            }
        }
        $oTable.fnDraw();
    });
}
```

But it didn't work. There is no error, but the data is still the same, without any change.

Comment: It's a customised search. using external inputs, so it doesn't use any `sSearch_` position. But instead add new fields to the array

Comment: What version of DataTables are you using?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com [This version](https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package)

Comment: You're pointing to server-side code for Laravel, but I needed to know the version of jquery.datatables.js which is listed in the first line of the file. However I answered your question already because solution didn't depend on the DataTables version.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Sorry, my mistake. it's **@version 1.9.4** with *DataTools*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying values of INPUT and SELECT only once during initialization. Instead you should do it every time the data is requested from the server.

So you can modify your initialization code so that you retrieve INPUT and SELECT values on every call to function defined with `fnServerParams`.

Below I just moved your code into `fnServerParams` callback.

```
var dt = jQuery(".dataTable");
if(jQuery().dataTable && dt.length > 0) {
    dt.each(function () {
        var e = {
            sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
            fnServerParams: function(aoData){
                // If has external filters
                if(!!jQuery(this).data("searchbox")) {
                    var search_box = jQuery(jQuery(this).data("searchbox"));

                    var additional_filters = [];
                    jQuery.each(search_box.find('input,select'), function(i, v){
                        additional_filters.push({
                            name: jQuery(v).attr('name'),
                            value: jQuery(v).val()
                        });
                    });

                    if (additional_filters.length > 0) {
                        for (var i=0; i < additional_filters.length; i++) {
                            var filter = additional_filters[i];
                            aoData.push( { "name": filter.name, "value": filter.value } );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        jQuery(this).dataTable(e);
    });
}
```

Then your `RefreshDataTables()` calling `$oTable.fnDraw()` should work.

See the example below for code and demonstration. Please note, that I'm using [jQuery Mockjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax) plug-in just for the sake of demonstrating Ajax request, it's not needed for production code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // AJAX emulation for demonstration only
  $.mockjax({
    url: '/test/0',
    responseTime: 200,
    response: function(settings) {
      console.log("Request data: ", settings.data);

      this.responseText = {
        "aaData": [
          [
            "Trident",
            "Internet Explorer 4.0",
            "Win 95+",
            "4",
            "X"
          ],
          [
            "Trident",
            "Internet Explorer 5.0",
            "Win 95+",
            "5",
            "C"
          ],
          [
            "Trident",
            "Internet Explorer 5.5",
            "Win 95+",
            "5.5",
            "A"
          ]
        ]
      };
    }
  });

  
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "/test/0",
    "bServerSide": true,
    "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {

      // If has external filters
      if (!!jQuery(this).data("searchbox")) {
        var search_box = jQuery(jQuery(this).data("searchbox"));

        var additional_filters = [];
        jQuery.each(search_box.find('input,select'), function(i, v) {
          additional_filters.push({
            name: jQuery(v).attr('name'),
            value: jQuery(v).val()
          });
        });

        if (additional_filters.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < additional_filters.length; i++) {
            var filter = additional_filters[i];
            aoData.push({
              "name": filter.name,
              "value": filter.value
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  
  $('#btn').on('click', function(){
     $('#example').dataTable().fnDraw();  
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <p id="searchbox">
    <input type="text" name="param1" value="" placeholder="param1">
    <button id="btn" type="button">Search</button>
  </p>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" data-searchbox="#searchbox">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="20%">Rendering engine</th>
        <th width="25%">Browser</th>
        <th width="25%">Platform(s)</th>
        <th width="15%">Engine version</th>
        <th width="15%">CSS grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I add the same code as you, but the data sent was the same as in the first `draw`.

Comment: Now that I saw. There is an error. the `aoData` is not define. using the example above. I'm trying to make this work.

Comment: I tried to encapsulate the `for` with `this._fnServerParams = function (aoData) {` but now it doesn't pass any parameter at all, but I think this is the right path.

Comment: @MichelAyres, there was an error in the code, which is corrected. Added an example for demonstration, see console for request data.

Comment: Amazing. Before your edit, I have tested it with a variable like you did `fnServerParams: function(aoData){`, but didn't work. I must have forgot something or even forgot to update the `gulp`. Thanks a lot